# Materialize Carousel with Images disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using Materialize.js for some of the components and JS libraries they have available. One that I have been using is the 'carousel' component. I have it set up with three slides each with an `<h5>` and a `<p>` element in the slide container. This shows up exactly how it's expected. Once I add an `<img>` element into the slide, the entire carousel disappears. Here is what I am talking about:

working Carousel code:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center z-depth-5" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
        <paper-button raised class="carousel_button" id="top_button">Download Now</paper-button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#one" id="c_one">
        <div class="carousel_item_inner">
            <h5>Plan</h5>
            <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#two" id="c_two">
        <div class="carousel_item_inner">
            <h5>Create</h5>
            <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#three" id="c_three">
        <div class="carousel_item_inner">
            <h5>Generate</h5>
            <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS:[EDITTED]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.parallax').parallax();
                $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({full_width: true});
                $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
                $('.stat_circles').addClass('animate');
            });
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Once I add an `<img>` element into one of the .carousel_item_inner `<div>`'s, the carousel completely disappears. Here is one of the carousel-item's with the `<img>`:

```
<div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#one" id="c_one">
    <div class="carousel_item_inner">
        <h5>Plan</h5>
        <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
        <img src="images/plan.PNG">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here it is after that `<img>` element is there:

[image]

Really confused as to why the entire carousel disappears with an `<img>` in the slide container. All help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is a link to the Materialize Carousel as well: http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

EDIT:
Here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5cjaduwv/9/

Comment: Tried your code with an image from lorempixel. It is working fine. The thing is that the carousel waits for the image to load, so if it appears white for you could be an image loading issue.

Comment: I have tried it with a lorem ipsum image but same issues, I have placed a jsfiddle above so the error can be seen irt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for a sanity check can you try wrapping that js in a document ready. It may be that the js is called before your image is loading. Also be sure you are loading those scripts at the bottom of your page as you may have images taking too long to load which are dependent on the libs.

```
        // Load your JS files here in order of dependencies 
        // such as: jQuery, Bootstrap, other libs and lastly your custom js files
        // KEEP your CSS files in the head of your template.
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({full_width: true});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was able to reproduce your error in a fiddle and it came down to JS dependencies with jQuery and materialize. Can you share your list of scripts and where they are located. I usually keep them at the end of body so the DOM loads first. jQuery should be the first lib with the others following below it.

Comment: The js has been wrapped in a document ready function the whole time, here is my document ready function:

I have editted my JS above for formatting, check the JS above to see the function that is rendering the carousel.

Comment: How about putting up a fiddle?

Comment: Just added the jsFiddle above, it will still make the carousel disappear once the <img> is placed in the carousel-item.

Comment: Yeah I got it working on your fiddle. Go to the javascript pane and click on the cog icon and set the script to onDomready vs onLoad. It's just a race condition I think. Be sure to load your libs just before the /body tag. Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: So i have all the libraries loading in the <head>, what you're saying is I need to have all the <script> and <style> imports loading under my markup in the body?

Comment: Yes load all the JS libs at the end of the body. You keep the CSS in the head.

Comment: Thank you!!! Just separated the scripts and CSS, it is working now. I see now differences between domReady and onLoad. Thank you again, always appreciate a chance to learn while fixing my code!

I have one question: I have webcomponents.js loading as well, for use with Polymer Elements. These all use html imports, should they be loaded in the head or in the body? As well should I be loading webcomponents.js in the head or the body?

Comment: Yes webcomponents.js should be loaded at the end of the body because it interacts with the DOM. Example if an element has not loaded yet and the script is attempting to access it then it's going to fail. Rarely do you need to have a script in head these days. And a lot of scripts are dependent on jQuery. so all those types of scripts would need to load after jQuery. All else fails when you are adding a new script read documentation from the third-party site. On rare occassion they recommend it to be placed in the head. Very rare...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put `<img>` element between the `<p>` elements ?

Comment: Still not working there, I tried in the <p> & </p>, in between the closing </h5> and before the starting <p>, but still just disappears whenever the <img> is there. Tried to force a height and a z-index but it still will not show up whatsoever.

Comment: You forgot the "/"
It's like that : <img ... />

Answer (score 0):

Materialize's default carousel doesn't seem to be designed to hold img and text in a same container, they simply display one after another.

Instead, try out the slider : http://materializecss.com/media.html

Comment: Please consider providing more details/explanations on how your proposed answer helps. Maybe add a code example.